# Return all rows from one table, and match rows from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following two tables:

ExchangeRate (T1):

```
CurrencyCode    Rate
CHF             6.9660
EUR             7.4445
GBP             8.2569
NOK             0.6686
```

Customer (T2):

```
CustomerNo   Name  Address     City    CurrencyCode
Test001      Test  1/2 Test     TA       NOK
Test002      Test  1/2 Test     EU       EUR
```

I want a result as below:

```
CurrencyCode CustomerNo   City   
CHF           NULL        NULL
EUR           NULL        NULL 
GBP           NULL        NULL 
NOK           Test001      TA
CHF           NULL        NULL
EUR           Test002      EU 
GBP           NULL        NULL 
NOK           NULL        NULL
```

I have tried this query

```
Select Er.CurrencyCode,Ca.CurrencyCode
From 
ExchangeRate Er
Left Outer Join Customer As Ca With(NoLock) On Ca.CurrencyCode=Er.CurrencyCode
where CA.CustomerCode='Test001'
```

but, I got this result

```
CurrencyCode CustomerNo   City   
NOK           Test001      TA
```

I need the result like `Cross Join`. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the respone. I need the result like cross join. Now I have edited my expected result place, please check now.

Comment: Yes I got an answer @DaleK

Comment: I am new to this. So it Required 15+ Reputation to Upvote any answer @DaleK

Comment: Your query selects two columns, but your results have three.  Your query uses `customerCode`, which is not in the table.  Your results have two different customers, but your filter condition only references one.  The question is quite confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` with a `case` expression to determine whether to display the results or not.

```
select Er.CurrencyCode
  , case when Ca.CurrencyCode = Er.CurrencyCode then Ca.CustomerNo end CustomerNo
  , case when Ca.CurrencyCode = Er.CurrencyCode then Ca.City end City
from ExchangeRate Er
cross join Customer Ca
where CA.CustomerCode = 'Test001'
```

Note: Don't use `nolock` unless you absolutely must and are clear about the possible consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your condition `CA.CustomerCode='Test001'` to `JOIN` instead of `WHERE` so it will return all rows from `ExchangeRate` and `CustomerNo` & `City` when CustomerCode = 'Test001' has matching `CurrencyCode`.

```
Select Er.CurrencyCode, Ca.CurrencyCode, Ca.CustomerNo, Ca.City
From ExchangeRate Er
Left Outer Join Customer As Ca With(NoLock) 
    On Ca.CurrencyCode = Er.CurrencyCode
```

---

Alternatively you can update `WHERE` condition and add `OR CA.CustomerNo IS NULL` as below.

```
Select Er.CurrencyCode, Ca.CurrencyCode, Ca.CustomerNo, Ca.City
From ExchangeRate Er
Left Outer Join Customer As Ca With(NoLock) 
    On Ca.CurrencyCode = Er.CurrencyCode
WHERE CA.CustomerCode = 'Test001' OR CA.CustomerNo IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is basically fine.  You just need to move the filter condition to the `on` clause:

```
Select Er.CurrencyCode, Ca.CurrencyCode
From ExchangeRate Er left join
     Customer Ca
     On Ca.CurrencyCode = Er.CurrencyCode and
        CA.CustomerCode = 'Test001'
```